# CRM 2011 isn't passing values to word for a Mail Merge

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, mailmerge

I'm trying to get a mail merge working with Dynamics CRM 2011 but when word opens, the screen doesn't seem to pass over any of the data.

This is when using the contact entity and when trying to use First and last name as a simple example.

I have attached a screenshot of the mappings with no data being displayed.

Any ideas on what could cause this?

Note: We had this issue about 8 months ago but we changed from a managed to unmanaged solution and it seemed to start working, it has since stopped working again.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this was a simple error on my behalf. I haven't used mail merge with CRM before and therefore wasn't aware of the Send Marketing Mail field, which was not set for all of our contacts, meaning know one was in the list.

So in fact the values were being passed over all along, but mail merge excludes people who don't have the marketing option set to true. Makes sense!